# How to optimize (TimescaleDB/PostgreSQL) timeseries SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, timescaledb

I have time series data and I'm trying to make as efficient DB structure and query as it's possible.

I've indexed id's and datetime as desc in table.

```
SELECT
   table.id,
   To_char(Time_bucket('2 hours', datetime) at time zone 'utc', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"') AS time,
   Avg(value) AS value,
   mapping.description 
FROM
   table 
   JOIN
      mapping 
      ON table.id = mapping.id 
WHERE
   table.id IN
   (
      10000,
      10004,
      1001,
      10005
   )
   AND datetime BETWEEN '2019-09-25' AND '2019-09-30' 
GROUP BY
   time,
   table.id,
   mapping.description 
ORDER BY
   time DESC;
```

Table structure as below

```
                        Table "public.table"
  Column  |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default
----------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 datetime | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |
 id       | integer                     |           | not null |
 value    | double precision            |           |          |
Indexes:
    "table_datetime_idx" btree (datetime DESC)
    "table_id_datetime_idx" btree (id, datetime DESC)
```

Mapping table

```
                      Table "public.mapping"
   Column    |       Type        | Collation | Nullable | Default
-------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id          | integer           |           | not null |
 tagname     | character varying |           |          |
 description | character varying |           |          |
 unit        | character varying |           |          |
 mineu       | double precision  |           |          |
 maxeu       | double precision  |           |          |

Indexes:
     "mapping_id_idx" btree (id)
```

No errors but still I wonder this doesn't look good or efficient enough. Execution takes now around 14 seconds. What would be the easiest solutions to optimize this query?

Below the result of EXPLAIN ANALYZE

```
 GroupAggregate  (cost=250964.79..265699.28 rows=453369 width=73) (actual time=10247.641..11501.894 rows=60 loops=1)
   Group Key: (to_char(timezone('utc'::text, time_bucket('02:00:00'::interval, _hyper_1_4_chunk.datetime)), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"'::text)), _hyper_1_4_chunk.id, mapping.description
   ->  Sort  (cost=250964.79..252098.21 rows=453369 width=73) (actual time=10237.177..10481.057 rows=421712 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (to_char(timezone('utc'::text, time_bucket('02:00:00'::interval, _hyper_1_4_chunk.datetime)), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"'::text)) DESC, _hyper_1_4_chunk.id, mapping.description
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 33816kB
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=7228.67..196570.23 rows=453369 width=73) (actual time=81.488..5779.432 rows=421712 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (_hyper_1_4_chunk.id = mapping.id)
               ->  Append  (cost=7215.89..186363.19 rows=452059 width=20) (actual time=81.299..3680.949 rows=421712 loops=1)
                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on _hyper_1_4_chunk  (cost=7215.89..129006.87 rows=363549 width=20) (actual time=81.298..3350.870 rows=336860 loops=1)
                           Recheck Cond: ((id = ANY ('{10000,10004,1001,10005}'::integer[])) AND (datetime >= '2019-09-25 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (datetime <= '2019-09-30 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                           Heap Blocks: exact=61125
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on _hyper_1_4_chunk_table_id_datetime_idx  (cost=0.00..7125.00 rows=363549 width=0) (actual time=69.006..69.006 rows=336860 loops=1)
                                 Index Cond: ((id = ANY ('{10000,10004,1001,10005}'::integer[])) AND (datetime >= '2019-09-25 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (datetime <= '2019-09-30 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on _hyper_1_3_chunk  (cost=1766.52..57356.32 rows=88510 width=20) (actual time=20.876..311.867 rows=84852 loops=1)
                           Recheck Cond: ((id = ANY ('{10000,10004,1001,10005}'::integer[])) AND (datetime >= '2019-09-25 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (datetime <= '2019-09-30 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                           Heap Blocks: exact=16352
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on _hyper_1_3_chunk_table_id_datetime_idx  (cost=0.00..1744.39 rows=88510 width=0) (actual time=17.291..17.291 rows=84852 loops=1)
                                 Index Cond: ((id = ANY ('{10000,10004,1001,10005}'::integer[])) AND (datetime >= '2019-09-25 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (datetime <= '2019-09-30 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
               ->  Hash  (cost=8.46..8.46 rows=346 width=33) (actual time=0.163..0.163 rows=346 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 31kB
                     ->  Seq Scan on mapping  (cost=0.00..8.46 rows=346 width=33) (actual time=0.019..0.097 rows=346 loops=1)
 Planning time: 1.008 ms
 Execution time: 11507.606 ms
```

Comment: You have to specify the table structures or at least where *all* the columns come from.

Comment: Can you do EXPLAIN ANALYZE on the query and share the result? It will allow to see how big are the chunks and how well it is planned. The disk speed might also affect the query execution time. Do you run TimescaleDB locally or in a cloud?

Comment: Running on local virtual server. Edited result of EXPLAIN ANALYZE into post.

Comment: ```Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 33816kB```

You are swapping to disk in order to merge the result.  Need to increase the size allocated to shared_buffers to fit the sort into memory.

Have you run timescaledb-tune?  https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-tune

Comment: @MikeFreedman: `shared_buffers` has nothing to do with memory needed for sorting. That is controlled by `work_mem`

Answer (score 2):

If you raise `work_mem` to 100 MB or more, the sort should be calculated in memory, which will speed up execution.

If you raise `work_mem` even more, you might get a faster hash aggregate instead of a group aggregate, which will make the query even faster.

I don't think there is anything you can do about the index scans.